# What are the "nosewheel stop" and "wheel stop" times in this Wikipedia article?

Tags: landing, space-shuttle

In the [wikipedia article on STS-68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-68), in the [landing section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-68#Landing), it says

> Nose wheel stop at 13:02:21 EDT. Wheel stop at 13:03:08 EDT

How can the nosewheel stop time be 47 seconds before wheel stop (which I assume refers to mainwheel stop?) What do these two times refer to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should read "nose wheel *touchdown*" instead of nose wheel stop. The Wikipedia article for a different flight, [STS-70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-70#Landing), says:

> Nose gear touchdown occurred at 8:02:11 am EDT with wheels stop at 8:02:57 am.

That is, 46 seconds from nosewheel down to full stop. I found another flight with 48 seconds nose-down to full-stop time, so the STS-68 time given seems consistent.

I presume that different pedants have different definitions of flight duration, hence the calling out of two different time stamps for "landing".